# Finding out whether a progression is A.P. or G.P. and find the first four terms of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

**Question**: The sum of the first n terms of the series ie given by, $ S_n = \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $. Find out whether the sequence is an A.P. or a G.P. and find the first four terms of the series. Hence deduce the sum $ 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + 20^2 $.

I thought of solving it by substituting both the sum formulas of A.P. $S_n = {n\over 2} (2a+(n-1)d)$ and G.P. $ \frac {a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ into $S_n$, but both of them became a mess and I got stuck.

Comment: First term is $S_1 = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{6}=1$. Start by finding the next three ones.

Comment: @dxiv thank you. it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $n=1,2,3,4$ into the formula.
$S_1=1$
$S_2=5$
$S_3=14$
$S_4=30$

$a_1=S_1=1$
$a_2=S_2-S_1=4$
$a_3=S_3-S_2=9$
$a_4=S_4-S_3=16$

It's clear that $a_n=n^2$. So, $$S_n=\sum^n_{k=1}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$You can prove this easily by induction. Hence, $$S_{20}=1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + 20^2$$

Comment: "*prove this easily by induction*" $\,$ No induction needed, $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}- \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}=...$

Answer (score 0):

Note that your sum takes the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^{20} a_n \text{ when } a_n = n^2$$

Ask yourself:

- Is $a_n - a_{n-1}$ always the same value for every $n$? If so, it is an arithmetic progression; if not, it is not.
- Is $a_n/a_{n-1}$ always the same value for every $n$? If so, it is a geometric progression; if not, it is not.
- The value of your sum is $S_{20}$; use your special formula for $n=20$. We can see this because of a known identity ([more info on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/)),
  $$
  S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
  $$
  The first four partial sums of the series are $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$, by likewise letting $n=1,2,3,4$. The first four summands are just what you get with $n^2$  for $n=1,2,3,4$ -- it's not immediately clear to me whether "terms of the series" is meant as partial sums or the summands here. I would normally assume the summands, but that's too trivial a question in my opinion.

---

Also, the sum of a finite geometric progression is not the formula you stated. The formula you stated has $1-r$ cancelling, which would be pointless in a formula. The proper formula is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k = \frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$$

You certainly cannot plug these for $n$, because $n$ is just the upper bound of the sum, but these formulas are for the sum of every term in the sum; there is an important difference there you should been keenly mindful of.

Comment: I miswrote the r^n with r, but I think it isn't r^(n+1).

Comment: But thanks for taking notice of it, and answering.

Comment: It is indeed $r^{n+1}$, as seen, for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Finite_series)